# Azure stored procedure in Azure portal not working although SQL query works

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

The following stored procedure failed to produce any result even though the SQL query used in it produced results when tested on the Azure portal.

```js
function checktemp() {
    var context = getContext();
    var container = context.getCollection();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    let query = `SELECT DISTINCT {"Elevator": t.connectiondeviceid,
        "Vibration": t["vibration"],
        "Temperature": t["temperature"]} 

    FROM t 
    WHERE t["temperature"] > 75
    AND t.EventEnqueuedUtcTime > "2019-08-03T20:30:51.905Z"
    ORDER BY t["temperature"] DESC`

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = container.queryDocuments(
        container.getSelfLink(), query,
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var body = { moststrain: feed[0] };
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

I expect to have items returned, but I always get 'no docs found'. My partition key is /ConnectionDeviceId.

Comment: Any sample documents you could provide?

Comment: Sample: `{
    "vibration": 0,
    "temperature": 74.7410630399785,
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2019-08-05T06:18:57.1967352Z",
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2019-08-05T06:16:24.258Z",
    "CorrelationId": null,
    "ConnectionDeviceId": "1bc0a201-0fd4-4b90-932e-f1aefeab0cba.elevator-01.7",
    "id": "8f1def7a-5040-bedd-c038-a45327c504db",
    "_rid": "G7ktANUcHmkCAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/G7ktAA==/colls/G7ktANUcHmk=/docs/G7ktANUcHmkCAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"2300b5a6-0000-0d00-0000-5d47ca690000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1564985961}`

Comment: Is this a partitioned collection? Stored Procedures execute for a particular PK, are you using the PK of the expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested your sample document with your stored procedure code,it works for me.Your SP structure should be fine.

[image]

Some mistake with the spell of property(`ConnectionDeviceId`) you provide,it should be `ConnectionDeviceId` in sql:`t.ConnectionDeviceId`.

[image]

To solve such issue like something works in the portal, no results in SP, i suggest you removing query statements partially step by step to locate which part of SQL causes no results.

---

Anyway,the issue is related to partition key. When you query data in the portal, it scans all the partitions. However,if you execute SP,it only scans specific partition.

Since the data is partitioned on 'connectiondeviceid', I was supposed to provide a value of it during execution of the stored procedure.

Comment: thanks for looking at my problem. Like you, I get the expected results when I run the query in the Azure portal. But when this same query is included in the stored procedure, nothing is returned. So I suspect it is not a problem of my query but perhaps its a problem with my configuration of the cosmos db container. Unfortunately I cannot pin point it.

Comment: @EdmondSesay my container is new-created container,it's all default configured. Maybe i don't think it's about configuration about container. Another possible reason i came up is related to partition. When you query data in the portal, it scans all the partitions. However,if you execute SP,it only scans specific partition.Maybe there is no match data in that partition?

Comment: the issue was with the partition key which you pointed out. Since I had partitioned my data on 'connectiondeviceid', I was supposed to provide a value of it during execution of the stored procedure. Problem was solved when I did. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @EdmondSesay Cheers! I summarized the solution in my answer,you could mark it for others' references. Thank you!